# Why is the Console Closing after I've included cin.get()?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've just started learning C++ using C++ Primer Plus but I'm having trouble with one of the examples. Like the book instructed I included `cin.get()` at the end to prevent the console from closing by itself. However, in this instance it still closes by itself unless I add two `cin.get()` statements which I don't understand. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2010.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int carrots;

    using namespace std;
    cout << "How many carrots do you have?" << endl;
    cin >> carrots;
    carrots = carrots + 2;
    cout << "Here are two more. Now you have " << carrots << " carrots.";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
cin >> carrots;
```

This line leaves a trailing newline token in the input stream, which then gets consumed by the next `cin.get()`. Just do a simple `cin.ignore()` directly before that:

```
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
```

Comment: Explained very well.

Answer (score 8):

Because `cin >> carrots` doesn't read the newline which you enter after  typying the integer, and `cin.get()` reads the newline left in the input stream, and then the program ends. That is why the console closes.

Answer (score 4):

```
cin >> carrots;
```

reads an `int` but leaves a newline behind.

```
cin.get();
```

reads that newline, and the program ends.

Answer (score 2):

```
cin >> carrots;
```

Gets an integer input and leaves a new line after pressing enter key.

```
cin.ignore();
```

Place this after getting inputs to avoid the exit of console.