# Prevent console from closing

Tags: c++, console, sleep

I tried `std::getchar();`, `cin::get();` and `system ("sleep");`, but nothing stops the console from closing, because it seems, that all of these functions misinterpret the pressed enter key that was supposed to confirm input for `scanf`. **How can I prevent the console from closing with a "Press enter / any key to close" behavior after scanf?** I don't want to use functions stopping the console totally from doing something for some time (like sleep) or non-portable functions (like `system ("sleep")`), unless such functions are the only ways.

```
int main () {
    wchar_t *user = new wchar_t[30];
    wscanf (L"%30ls", user);
    // Process data... (very short time)

    std::getchar ();

    return 0;
}
```

IDE: Visual Studio 2013 (12.0) Express
I don't know the compiler. I created an empty C++ project and didn't change any settings.

Comment: Show us the code please.

Comment: Have you tried invoking `std::getchar()` twice in a row?

Comment: You could use `scanf` again.

Comment: Which IDE/compiler are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the Console Closing after I've included cin.get()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398229/why-is-the-console-closing-after-ive-included-cin-get)

Comment: The possible duplicate has the same problem. After calling `scanf` there is a trailing `\n` that gets read by `cin.get()`, `system("pause")` and `std::getchar()`. So merlin's solution (using `std::getchar()` twice works pretty well.

Comment: Don't code it in. Run the program from the command line like it's meant to be run, or if running from the IDE, tell the IDE to pause it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
// do your stuff here

// prevent console from closing
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
cin.get();
```

Comment: Because this answer works as well as merlin's solution (using `getchar()` twice, you get the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use system("pause"); at the end of main() function.