# Console closes before i see my last line of code

Tags: c++, clion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgGbS.png)
This is my Program.

When i run it on the internal console in CLion it works fine but when i build it and open the .exe file I get the first line and after i enter the number and click enter the console closes. I don't understand why it worked just fine in Visual Studio.

and it doesn't work with a std::cin.get(); before the return 0;

Comment: Depending on the version, Visual Studio will pause after the program terminates and wait for a keypress. Try running your app in an already open console window.

Comment: Running an executable from the file explorer or clicking on a shortcut will have the executable close the window when the application finishes execution. This is the same for all applications, GUI based or console based. To keep the window open you can add code to your program to ask for a key before the last line of `int main()` or you can run your program from a cmd.exe window.

Comment: There are many questions about preventing the console window from closing: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169214/prevent-console-from-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169214/prevent-console-from-closing)

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a console application, run it from a console.