# Why does this particular cin.get() statement not work in C++ when I input a char?

Tags: c++

My problem is that I'm trying to make a menu as part of my program. There are conditional statements for input, and my `else` statement is supposed to say that input is invalid, and wait for input (so as to let the user know they entered something invalid).

This is the relevant snippet, and what I tried:

```
void main_menu() {
    int opt;
    system("CLS");
    std::cout << "Main Menu" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\n\nWhat would you like to do?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1) Fight" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2) Store" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3) Exit" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> opt;
    std::cin.ignore();

    if (opt == 1) {
        return main_menu();
    }
    else if (opt == 2) {
        return main_menu();
    }
    else if (opt == 3) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        system("CLS");
        std::cout << "Invalid!" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get(); //error, but not seen in list or console
    }
}
int main() {
    main_menu();
    return 0;
}
```

What I seem to have screwed up on is the `else`. When I run it, the code seemingly passes the `std::cin.get()` I've set up.

My desired output:

```
Input = 1 // valid input
go to statement 1 (empty for time being.)

Input = 6 // invalid, but is handled with the else:
cout << "Invalid!" << ....
//pause

Input = 'a' //invalid, should be like above:
cout << "Invalid!" << ....
//pause // in reality, it passes
```

I have already tried some methods and looked at some posts in sites other than SO (see post [Why is the Console Closing after I've included cin.get()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398229/why-is-the-console-closing-after-ive-included-cin-get)) (I have tried the `cin.ignore()` after `cin >> var` method already, not working), but none work.

It does say about newlines and such, but I don't understand about it. Can someone explain how the trailing newlines work, and why is my snippet not working?

**EDIT:** Other statements of `cin.get()` have worked in my actual code.

**EDIT:** I tried inputting an invalid option other than a number, but it didn't work (say, chars). Nums work though. So the question is now about handling data types other than ints, floats, doubles, etc.

Comment: `opt` is `int` type, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I have read from the linked post that it might be a trailing newline from the int input.

Comment: Do `std::cout << (int)std::cin.get();` , then you can see what character was read.  You might have better luck if you ignore the rest of the line, instead of just one character, earlier on

Comment: Also it would be good specify the exact input you provide  to produce the unexpected behaviour. And post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your example works for me, however I did remove the `system` call.

Comment: How did you manage to compile code that does `return;` in a value-returning function?

Comment: You are making something up. Your `std::cin.get();` works as expected. So, it is not clear what "error" are you talking about. What made you think there was an "error" of any kind? "Not working" is not a meaningful description of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, was using `main()` as a holder for the recursive function's actual name.

Comment: @AnT I edited that it had to do with chars, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I took the returns out since I did not have the other functions. If an actual complete example existed it would make testing and debugging much easier.

Comment: you haven't stated your expected behavior. It appears it would wait for an ENTER key and then exit the program.

Comment: Finally you post enough code and what you want.  Inputting a char leaves the stream in an error state because it is expecting an int so `get` fails, you need `cin.clear()` to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

by default, ingore will only ignore 1 character. There are at least 2 characters after the input in windows \r and \n.

You would be better to do:

```
cin.ignore(999,'\n')
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, thanks for the advice though.

Comment: `\r\n` is how newlines are stored in files; the operating system will convert it to `\n` when a program looks

Comment: No, in text streams Windows end-of-line markers will be seen as a single `\n` character.

Comment: modern console may differ, but back in DOS days it definitely sent both with one keystroke.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey perhaps you used a different input method (such as `getch` which reads console directly rather than the input stream)